# Bridge rectifier homework

Tags: circuit-analysis, rectifier

A bridge-rectifier circuit with a filter capacitor has \$R=100\Omega\$. The secondary transformer delivers a sinusoid of \$12V\$ (RMS) and has a frequency of \$60 Hz\$. The diodes have \$VD = 0.8 V\$ each.

(a) What will be the value of the filter capacitor so that the ripple voltage is limited to below \$0.5 V\$ peak-to-peak? 
**Answer: 2562 uF**

(b) What is the DC voltage at the output of the system?
**Answer: 15.12V**

(c) What is the conduction angle for the diode?
**ans: 0.678**

I tried to approach the part a by using the formula:

$$V_{ripple} = \frac{V_{peak} - V_{diode\;drop}}{R \cdot F \cdot C}$$

I get 5390 uF. I do not understand what is wrong. Similarly for part b, I do not know which formula to use. Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, he did show his formula and computation. The answer lies in the fact that he used the wrong formula. I agree that he should include a Homework tag. In other words, he should read the FAQ. But it's his first time, so I'd give him a break.

Comment: Agreed, the effort is there. The title leaves something to be desired...

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - [The homework tag has been invented before and we all agreed it is not a good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: -5 for this question? Srsly? He did show his work.

Answer (score 3):

In part a, you are using the formula for a half wave rectifier. They seem to want a full wave.

For part b, we usually assume the ripple is symmetrical. So, since we know the highest point of the ripple (\$\sqrt2*12 - 2V_{diode}\$) and we know the ripple magnitude from the same formula of part a (0.5V when you plug in the cap value), we can say that the average value of that waveform is the peak minus half of the ripple (which gives you 15.12V).

Comment: does that mean that formula to be used is  V(ripple) = [V(peak) - 2V(diode drop)]/2[RFC].

Comment: Still unsure on how to solve (b).

Comment: Yeah that's better for the formula. Hold on I'll edit that in.

Comment: I used V(peak) - 2V(diode drop) - V(ripple)/2 for part b and the answer works now. Is it  the right way?

Comment: Oh yeah, good call I forgot the diodes before. Edited.